# How to view the All Checkout files in a project in VSS?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, vcs-checkout

I want to see all checkout files in a project in VSS. is there a way to view all of checkout files at once?.

Answer (score 28):

If you are trying to do this from within VSS

- Click View->Search->Status Search (or
  Press Ctrl+S)
- Change the Status Search to either
  All or Per User
- Change the Search to the desired
  Option
- Click OK

Another real nice tool I found once is

[VssReporter 2.1 - A Visual SourceSafe reporting tool for build administrators](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/VssReporter.aspx)